# Breakers in a 30 amp panel

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a 30 amp panel in my garage with a 2pole 30amp main breaker.  The panel is fed from another 2 pole 30 amp breaker located next to my electrical meter.   I have 3 15 amp breakers in the panel running 3 outlets and 2 sets of lights.   Can I install a 30 amp breaker in the panel to install and RV outlet?

Comment: A panel picture could help,  but this type of expansion is exactly why the sub panel was installed: (to add circuits as needed).  Since you have both 120 legs and the 240 available for the new rv circuit, be sure to "ballance" loads if your putting in a 30 amp single pole rv circuit (pick the pole not used by the lights, or garage)